# Detectin collisions between blocks and player

Tags: java, block, collision-detection

I'm working on some collision detection stuff for my game. Essentially the player checks collision with the y-axis and it's fin, but once I break a block through the y, I can no-clip through the x-axis(which are solid blocks). Could someone lead me into a good direction to where I can extend my java programming knowledge?

```
private void checkForCollision(){
    for(int i = 0; i< world.arrayNum; i++){
        if(playerRect.intersects(world.blocks[i]) && world.isSolid[i]){
            yDirection = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.Add a short, complete program showing your problem. 2.Stick to one question per post.

Comment: Share the code for the intersects function.